# Is there a maximum limit of s3_targets / data stores that can be added to an AWS Glue Crawler using Terraform?

Tags: terraform, aws-glue, terraform-provider-aws

I have several thousand table extracts (CSV) stored in an S3 bucket that I need to crawl. There is no partitioning required and each folder should be treated as an individual table. To prevent Glue from forcing partitioning of similar tables I need to include each folder as an separate data store.

Using the console it is tedious to add new data stores as you have to do them one at a time, so I am using Terraform to do this.

Example:

```
resource "aws_glue_crawler" "multi_test" {
  database_name = "test"
  name          = "multi_test"
  role          = "${data.aws_iam_role.GlueServiceRole.arn}"

  s3_target {
    path = "s3://${aws_s3_bucket.test_bucket.bucket}/data_in/test/multi/table00001"
  }

  s3_target {
    path = "s3://${aws_s3_bucket.test_bucket.bucket}/data_in/test/multi/table00002"
  }

  ...
```

I have tested this so far with up to 250 sample tables, but wonder is there a limit to how many I can add, either in Terraform or AWS? Has anybody tried this with 1000+ individual s3_targets/data stores?

Many thanks.

Mark

Comment: Can you share an example of how your data is structured in S3 because I think Glue should handle this fine as a single crawler as long as you structure it in S3 properly.

Comment: An example would be:

bucket/data_in/finance/gl/gl_period_sets
bucket/data_in/finance/gl/gl_period_types
bucket/data_in/finance/gl/gl_periods

With the crawler pointing at bucket/data_in/finance/gl it merges all three into one new table called gl instead of three separate ones.